# Por quê o "ion-slides" não está funcionando corretamente no meu aplicativo?

Tags: ionic, mobile, app, angular-7, ionic4

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo usando Ionic 4.

Em uma das páginas que comecei a criar, estou tentando usar o componente "ion-slides".

Inseri um componente básico em uma página html, só para testar, desse jeito:

```html
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Não fiz nenhuma alteração no arquivo typescript dessa página, como podem ver abaixo:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-novo-teste',
  templateUrl: './novo-teste.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./novo-teste.page.scss'],
})
export class NovoTestePage implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

O problema é que a tela fica toda preta e o "ion-slide" ocupa somente a parte de cima da tela, como aparece na imagem abaixo:

[image: Print da tela onde ocorre o problema]
Estou usando o Google Chrome, e não apareceu nenhum erro no console do navegador.

Como resolvo isso?

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Provavelmente é algum Css em algum lugar que está provocando isso.

Comment: No ionic 3 era necessário [importar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/) o componente do slide, provavelmente no ionic 4 também seja necessário(achei [esse](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-multiple-slides-on-single-view-using-swiper-slider/#more-1410) exemplo de uso, talvez lhe ajude)

Answer (score 1):

Vou te passar um exemplo para ver se ajuda amigo:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slides-example',
  template: `
    <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  `
})
export class SlideExample {
  // Optional parameters to pass to the swiper instance. See http://idangero.us/swiper/api/ for valid options.
  slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 1,
    speed: 400
  };
  constructor() {}
}
```